# Send value in a database through jquery + ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to store the value "20_2018" (for example) with an id in my database. I want to count clicks on each downloading.

This is what I tried:

```
<html>
    <body>

    <a id="20_2018" rel="link1" href="folder.pdf">Download</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">             
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(\'a[rel="link1"]\').click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url: 'send.php', // folder for sending value in id to the database
                    data: 'id='+$(this).attr("id"), // take the value in the id
                    async: false
                });
                return true;              
            });
    </script>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Somehow this does not work. How can I implement a click count for downloads?

Answer (score 0):

First, prevent the default action with `preventDefault`, then send your request. After success, bring them to the file URL.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[rel="link1"]').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        // Gets href of the clicked anchor
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'send.php',
            data: 'id='+$(this).attr("id"),
            success: function(){
                // After recording click count, bring them there
                location.assign(href);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('failed');
            }
        });
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="20_2018" rel="link1" href="folder.pdf">Download</a>
```